# LDAP full-text search

Tags: full-text-search, ldap

Is LDAP able to do full-text search?

Are there any implementations that keep a full-text search index and use it as some kind of query?

Should I use other protocol than LDAP if I want to do proper full-text search queries?

Comment: I don't understant what you mean by "full-text search" LDAP_Search is somehow a full-text search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LDAP doesn't have any fulltext search, as far as I know - it's not designed for that.

However, depending on your needs, maybe the **Ambiguous Name Resolution** (ANR) could help. Read all about it (for Windows 2000 LDAP) here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243299

What it does is to allow you to define a part of your LDAP filter to be `(anr=SomeName)` and this "anr" value will be searched in the following attributes:

- GivenName
- Surname
- displayName
- LegacyExchangeDN
- msExchMailNickname
- RDN
- physicalDeliveryOfficeName
- proxyAddress
- sAMAccountName

So while it's not strictly a fulltext search, you do get some of the benefits.